# Action bar having two lines of text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I make this kind of actionbar, with two lines? The second line has an icon and a variable text defined inside the class.

[image]

Comment: You can nest views inside of your toolbar. It extends the ViewGroup, i.e. it can be a parent

Answer (score 0):

You can add two lines in Actionbar like Title and a Subtitle. For this, you need to set the `DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE`

I will suggest two resources for this. [example of setDisplayOptions implementation](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.support.v7.app.ActionBar/setDisplayOptions) and [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSubtitle(int))

You can use these codes too as your reference,

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Android Actionbar Title and SubTitle Example"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android action bar title and subtitle tutorial with example. learn 
        to add subtitle in android actionbar" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="ViralAndroid.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.actionbar_title_and_subtitle);

android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("ActionBar Title");
actionBar.setSubtitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFBF00'>Here ActionBar 
Subtitle</font>"));
}
```

For the icon, you can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int))